# query return only a row in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my model I have the follow query:

```
function myquerydata() {
   $data = array();
   $query = $this->db->query('select max(field1) as field11, max(field2) as field22, max(field3) as field33 from my_table');
   foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $row->field11;
        $row->field22;
        $row->field33;
    }
}
```

This query only return one row.

In my controller I have the next code:

```
$this->load->model('my_model');
$fields=$data['rows']=$this->my_model->myquerydata();
```

My question is how can I call the data field11, field22, field33 from controller.  When I apply a foreach appears error:

```
foreach ($fields as $row){
  echo $row->field11,
  echo $row->field22,
  echo $row->field33,
}
```

What is my error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
function myquerydata() {

    $data = array();
    $query = $this->db->query('select max(field1) as field11, max(field2) as field22, max(field3) as field33 from my_table');
    //return the result and call from controller
    return $query->result();
}
```

And place the following in your controller

```
$this->load->model('my_model');
$fields=$data['rows']=$this->my_model->myquerydata();
print_r($fields);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function returns nothing. You must return data in order to work with it.

```
return $query->result();
```

Comment: I put return $query->result(); in my model and occurs this error:  Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in .....

Comment: What line? How does Sudhir's solution work? btw. result() method returns an object while result_array() return an array